# Как дождаться загрузки шрифта?

Tags: javascript, css, шрифты, angular2, webpack

Использую Angular2 и webpack. Стили подключены к компонентам, инкапсуляция не используется.

Возникает проблема с кастомными шрифтами. Некоторые компоненты определяют свои размеры, но из-за асинхронной загрузки шрифтов получается, что они замеряют размеры со стандартными шрифтами вместо кастомных.

Как это можно исправить?

Насколько я понимаю, никаких полезных в этом плане событий нет. Думал о проверке текущего шрифта с некоторой задержкой, но не смог найти, как определить текущий шрифт. `getComputedStyle` всегда возвращает вычисленное значение, независимо от того, загружен ли шрифт.

Возможно, есть какое-то решение, специфичное для webpack'а или ангуляра?

```js
~function () {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand&_='+Date.now();
  document.head.appendChild(link);
  
  var dest = document.getElementById('dest');
  console.log(getComputedStyle(dest).fontFamily);
  var width = getComputedStyle(dest).width;
  dest.style.width = width;
}();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family: initial;">Need to handle font loading</p>
<p id="dest">Need to handle font loading</p>
<p>Need to handle font loading</p>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/40537710/4928642)

Comment: link.onload=function(){alert('loaded');}; ?

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр, ну вебпак же.. Я не контролирую, когда он что делает, а содержимое стилей он вставляет тегом style со стилями внутри...